# http Post request with Typescript

Tags: typescript, http, post

I am trying to find an example of HTTP post request in Typescript but can only find examples that use Angular. Could someone point me in the right direction to find this or post a quick example here of using Post with JSON data to get a response JSON.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Update 2020:

Note that as of now, the global `fetch` is [available on all modern browsers and covers 95% of all web users](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch). If you need support for IE, read the original answer.

[MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) | [TypeScript Definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L18583)

Where the function is available in the `window` or `global` contexts, looks like:

```
    fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit): Promise<Response>;
```

so you can do:

```
const response = await fetch(myUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: content,
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'} });

if (!response.ok) { /* Handle */ }

// If you care about a response:
if (response.body !== null) {
  // body is ReadableStream<Uint8Array>
  // parse as needed, e.g. reading directly, or
  const asString = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(response.body);
  // and further:
  const asJSON = JSON.parse(asString);  // implicitly 'any', make sure to verify type on runtime.
}
```

### Original Answer:

If you want to use native JavaScript functions in TypeScript for your HTTP POST request, take a look at the [JSON](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json) and [POST](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#post) examples on YouMightNotNeedJQuery.com. Using that, you can implement your own:

```
// Using callbacks:
function request<Request, Response>(
        method: 'GET' | 'POST',
        url: string,
        content?: Request,
        callback?: (response: Response) => void,
        errorCallback?: (err: any) => void) {

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(method, url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            // Success!
            const data = JSON.parse(this.response) as Response;
            callback && callback(data);
        } else {
            // We reached our target server, but it returned an error
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function (err) {
        // There was a connection error of some sort
        errorCallback && errorCallback(err);
    };
    if (method === 'POST') {
        request.setRequestHeader(
            'Content-Type',
            'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    }
    request.send(content);
}

// Using promises:
function request2<Request, Response>(
    method: 'GET' | 'POST',
    url: string,
    content?: Request
): Promise<Response> {
    return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => {
        request(method, url, content, resolve, reject);
    });
}
```

`XMLHttpRequest` is a built-in JavaScript class and included in the TypeScript typings.

Comment: I added this before the send as well.   `for ( let header of headers ) {
   request.setRequestHeader( header.key, header.value );
  }` Then added a parameter to request `headers : Array<{ key : string, value : string }>,`

Answer (score 5):

Here is my very simple example to call GET or POST with Typescript only.

```
//-------------------------------------------------
// Simple function to GET or POST
function httpCall(method: string, url:string, data:any, callback:(result:any)=>any) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    if (callback) xhr.onload = function() { callback(JSON.parse(this['responseText'])); };
    if (data != null) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
    else xhr.send();
}
```

Optional input data (the post body) and callback.  The data and result are both assumed to be JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Sending form data.

```
Save(model: yourmodalarray[]): Observable<any> {

        var formData: FormData = new FormData();

        formData.append('id', '');
 const headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'
        });
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


        return this._http
            .post(this._baseUrl + 'Save', formData, options)
            .map(res => <any>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);

    }
```

Comment: This example seems to use Angular's HttpClient as well -- the author is asking for otherwise.

Comment: Not native typescript