# How to serve POST request with Node using Express and Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I have been working with typescript on Angular and now trying to use to it do server-side scripting with Node and Express. I have successfully configured the basic typescript settings as follows:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
          "*": [
              "node_modules/*"
          ]
      }
  },
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

tslint.json

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {
        "trailing-comma": [ false ]
    },
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

I have also configured a basic server as below:

**app.ts**

```
import express from 'express';
import { userModel } from './UserModel';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{res.send('Hello from the server');});

app.post('/fetch', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(typeof userModel);
    console.log("Body=> ", req.body); // logs undefined
    userModel.setUsername(req.body.u);
    userModel.setPassword(req.body.p);

    console.log("Usrname=> ", userModel.getUserName);
    console.log("Password=> ", userModel.getPassword);
});

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
    console.log('running on port 3000');
})
```

The basic get request works fine and returns `Hello from the server` when i hit `http://localhost:3000/` with postman. However, when i try to send a post request, the statement `console.log("Body=> ", req.body);` logs `undefined`. I searched for a solution but most of them are for `Angular`. I also saw the following post on stackoverflow: [http Post request with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49014689/10527471) but the answer makes use of promises.

Is there a simpler way to serve post requests with typescript on node server?

Comment: Try adding `app.use(express.bodyParser());` middleware

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeaScript at all. Just look up Postman and JavaScript

Comment: @Rashomon using ```app.use(bodyParser.json());``` worked. thanks

Comment: @AluanHaddad when i was using plain javascript, ```app.use(express.json())``` worked fine. After configuring typescript, now i have to use ```app.use(bodyParser.json());``` to get things working. Although i am not sure why because body-parser is pure node library and not just a part of express.

Comment: That cannot be the case. Something else has changed unless there's a bug in typescript